# Years to Learn to Build an IC

Tags: reference-request

So, for a couple years now I've been quoting someone that said that it would take about 150 years of education to learn everything it'd take to build an integrated circuit, start to finish.

Thing is, now I can't find my original source. Does this figure sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: This is not a meaningful number - just assume that there are 25 different types of expert knowledge required, and that an MS requires 6 years of study. It's a throw-away line in a pop-science talk.